# Using required checkbox validation to prevent form submission

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox, require

I've got some code that checks if at least one checkbox is selected and then submits the form (MailChimp). My problem is I don't know how to stop the MailChimp submission if it catches that no checkboxes are selected. Right now it shows the alert and then submits the form anyway ... little help.

```
<form onsubmit="valthis()" action="//mailchimp form" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

// form html

        <script>function valthis() {
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
var isChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
            isChecked = true;
        };
    };
    if ( isChecked ) {
        alert( 'At least one checkbox is NOT checked!' );
        }   
}</script>

<input type="submit" value="Subscribe to notifications" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `return` the value of your JS function when processing data:

```
<form onsubmit="return valthis()" action="//mailchimp form" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

<script>
function valthis() {
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
    var isChecked = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
            isChecked = true;
            break; //don't need to continue the loop once a checkbox was found
        }
    }

    if ( !isChecked ) {
        alert( 'At least one checkbox is NOT checked!' );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
</script>

<input type="submit" value="Subscribe to notifications" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event to the form on submit

```
document.getElementsByName("subscribe").onsubmit(function(event) {
    if(!isChecked) { //If not checked
        event.preventDefault(); // stops the form submitting
    }
});
```

If no checkbox's are checked [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). This stops the form from submitting

Comment: I added the `document.getElementsByName` code below the current javascript. No go. Am I putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: `function valthis() {
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
var isChecked = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
            isChecked = false;
        };
    };
    if ( isChecked ) {
        alert( 'At least one checkbox is NOT checked!' );
        }
                        document.getElementsByName("subscribe").onsubmit(function(event) {
    if(!isChecked) { //If not checked
        event.preventDefault(); // stops the form submitting
    }
});
}`

Comment: Like @user5753132 said you need to add it outside the function